# Arithmetic Expressions Evaluation with Stack in Java

Tags: java, math, stack, expression

I want to write a code in java that evaluates an expression, like if the parentheses are closed as well as the brackets etc., but I must do it using a stack. I already have made the Stack interface, StackEmptyException class and StackFullException class.

```
public interface Stack
{
public int size( );
// Returns the size of the Stack

public boolean isEmpty( );
// Returns true if the Stack is empty

public boolean isFull( );
// Returns true if the Stack is full

public Object top( ) throws StackEmptyException;
// Returns the top item of the Stack

public void push(Object item) throws StackFullException;
// Adds a new item into the Stack

public Object pop( ) throws StackEmptyException;
// Removes the top item of the Stack

}//End of interface Stack
```

Comment: Maybe I  am reading this wrong but all of these depend on how you have implemented your stack

Comment: Could you define what your input looks like? I presume is something like `(1 + 1) * 2` but still...

Comment: for example: (2+1)*4*(3+1) is correct, 2+1)*2*(1+2) is wrong. I don't know what to do with the Stack.

Comment: The reverse polish notation should be more appropriate for the use of stack. Otherwise you will need the grammar for the expression in order to evaluate it. [Check this out](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReversePolishNotation.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use the the [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) for parsing mathematical expressions specified in **infix notation**.

e.g.:

```
(2+1)*4*(3+1)
```

[image]